# Java array rotation

Tags: java

I need help rotating an array by a distance according to `keyIndex`.

Here is my code:

```
char[] arr = new char[] {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
int keyIndex = 2;

char[] newArr = new char[26];

int last = arr[arr.length -1];
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = arr[i + keyIndex];
}
```

but I get an error and the last two characters are not being saved in elements 0, 1.

My teacher said this can be solved somehow by using modulus division in one line.

Comment: What part of your code is even *trying* to handle this case?  To even *detect* it?

Comment: What is `last` used for? (it's nothing at the moment, so you should delete it from your code)

Comment: okay. Do you have a solution for this? I am new to java and stack overflow and I don't know what I'm doing.

Comment: @Bohemian What is `newArr` used for?

Comment: @ScaryWombat I just removed it, I was trying to create a new array but decided to rotate the original one.

Comment: @ScaryWombat nothing, and that's part of the problem (assuming OP is not required to do an in-place rotation - something probably too advanced for OP at this stage in OP's coding journey)

Comment: @Bohemian sorry I'm adding it back. It might be simpler for me to understand if I create a new array with the rotated alphabets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your code's assignment line with this:

```
newArr[i] = arr[(i + keyIndex)%26];
```

The logic behind this is:
`%` (i.e. modulus) gives us the remainder on the division by a given number.

let i = 25 and keyIndex=2, so arr[(25 + 2) % 26] => arr[27 % 26] => arr[1]

so we can say modulus26  bounds a number in the range of 0 to 26, which is the need for this rotation operation

***Your Corrected Code:***

```
char[] arr = new char[] {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
int keyIndex = 2;
char[] newArr = new char[arr.length];
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    newArr[i] = arr[(i + keyIndex )%arr.length];
} 
//Print Array
```

Comment: or even `% newArr.length` for a more general solution. And how about some explanation?

Comment: So why should OP use modulus here? Please explain why this is necessary.

Comment: should not the assignment be to `newArr` ?

Comment: This doesn't work,  or rather the solution is incomplete.. You lose data.  We first overwrite arr[0] with 'c' (from arr[2]).  When we get to i=24, we overwrite arr[24] with arr[26%26], i.e. arr[0], which now has 'c'.   You wanted the old arr[0], which was 'a', but that now has been lost forever.

Comment: @passer-by if OP writes to `newArr` (which seems the original intention), instead of doing an in-place rotation, this problem is not an issue.

Comment: @Bohemian how would I be able to use arr[i] = arr[(i + keyIndex)%26]; and assign values to the new array?

Comment: Right - I just now caught up with the newArr "in, out, back in again" changes from the comments to the question.  Agree that avoiding in-place is likely the appropriate answer for the OP.

Comment: @Sharar294 `newArr[i] = arr[(i + keyIndex)%26];`

Comment: @Bohemian this works but I was wondering how it works for arr[24]. Anmol explained for 25 but what happens in regards to modulus division for 24?

Comment: @Sharar294 this might be a good time to use a debugger. All Java IDEs support debugging. Halt execution and step through the code to see what happens.

Comment: @Sharar294 for 24: 24+2 => 26, so 26 divided by 26 results in remainder of 0, so we get 0 as result

Comment: @Sharar294 Please do a Lil bit of dry run, for small problems, will give u much more understanding about these logics, and debugger is always there as your best companion, :-)

Comment: @Anmol will rotating it the other way require a similar process as what you suggested or is there a simple fix?

Comment: @Sharar294 for reverse rotation, replace + with - sign,
 
    `newArr[i] = arr[(arr.length + i - keyIndex )%arr.length];` 

and we are also adding the length to handle negative value.

Comment: '%' is not 'modulus' in Java, it's 'remainder' (the distinction shows up with negative numbers).  And perhaps that's easier to understand for the OP.  When you divide 24 by 26, the whole-number answer (in grade school terms) is 0, remainder 24.  When you divide 26 by 26, the  answer is 1, remainder 0.